# DataAdapter.UpdateCommand not working c#?

Tags: c#, database, datatable, dataadapter

I am using this code to update "SOME" columns in a table in my database. But everytime I try to do so an error is given.

**No value given for one or more required parameters.**

```
con.Open();
SlipDA = new OleDbDataAdapter();
string sqlUpdate = "Update tbl_Slip SET RaiseBasic=@RaiseBasic, OtherDed=@OtherDed, Arrears=@Arrears, Notes=@Notes WHERE SlipNo=@SlipNo";

SlipDA.UpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand(sqlUpdate, con);
SlipDA.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RaiseBasic", Convert.ToInt32(dRow[4].ToString()));
SlipDA.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OtherDed", Convert.ToInt32(dRow[5].ToString()));
SlipDA.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Arrears", Convert.ToInt32(dRow[7].ToString()));
SlipDA.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", dRow[8].ToString());
SlipDA.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SlipNo", dRow[0].ToString());

SlipDA.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

The table contains 9 columns but I only want to update a few.

Comment: It is int32
I corrected it but still error (Convert.ToInt32(dRow[0].ToString());

Comment: did you verify all your strings are not empty?

Answer (score 2):

This Could be the problem :

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing
>   parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an
>   OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the
>   question mark (?) placeholder must be used. For example: SELECT * FROM
>   Customers WHERE CustomerID = ?

source : [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx)

so basically your query should be like this :

```
string sqlUpdate = "Update tbl_Slip SET RaiseBasic= ?, OtherDed= ?, Arrears= ?, Notes= ? WHERE SlipNo= ?";
```

Comment: @WaqasAli just change the sqlUpdate as i stated above. the rest of your code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    string sqlUpdate = "Update tbl_Slip SET RaiseBasic=@RaiseBasic, OtherDed=@OtherDed, Arrears=@Arrears, Notes=@Notes WHERE SlipNo=@SlipNo";

    OleDbCommand UpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand(sqlUpdate, con);
    UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RaiseBasic", Convert.ToInt32(dRow[4].ToString()));
    UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OtherDed", Convert.ToInt32(dRow[5].ToString()));
    UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Arrears", Convert.ToInt32(dRow[7].ToString()));
    UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", dRow[8].ToString());
    UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SlipNo", dRow[0].ToString());

    con.Open();
    UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
```